# Remove space between container and navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple container which has navbar in it. Here is the code 
http://www.bootply.com/wPtXYaqV6m

I was expecting no space between the container and the navigation. How do I get rid of that space?

Comment: What is "the container"? `ui-layout-container`? If so, then remove the div with the ID `spacer`

Comment: is the white space is to be removed or what space ?

Comment: instead of a screenshot you should paste the url of your snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `navbar` has a border (bootstrap.min.css):

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

You can override it by specifying no borders in your own CSS file:

```
.navbar {
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: .navbar{margin-bottom: 0} was the key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the `container` with the `navbar` than increase `height` of the `navbar`

OR

If you want that `white` space betwenn `container` and `navbar` than simply remove `border` of `navbar`

Answer (score 0):

I think its border space space, if I am right what you think

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    /* border-color: #e7e7e7; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `white space` you are mentioning is a `border` and not really blank space. Override the CSS to remove the border and make it transparent.

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.container {
  background: red;
}
.navbar {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.navbar-default {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important; /* !important added for SO snippet, avoid it */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="navbar navbar-default " style="background: green">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- //navbar-header -->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="1">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2">Book</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="3">Hotels</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="4">Day trips</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="5">Ski+Snowboard Hire &amp; Lift Pass+School</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="6">Car Hire</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="7">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="8">Contact</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- //navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- end navbar -->
</div>
<!-- //container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

add following style in your code

```
.navbar.navbar-default {border-width:0px}
```